# Whats stopping me from using "Amazon.com" as my domain name?

Tags: wordpress, url, dns

I've been researching how to change a school club site's URL to a different domain. A lot of the process seems to be centered around changing URLs in the database and/or changing the address in WordPress settings.
Just out of curiosity, what exactly stops me from using say "amazon.com" as my Url since it doesn't seem like I need to prove that I own a certain URL before applying it to my site?

Answer (score 2):

As for what is stopping you setting your domain within your WordPress settings: nothing. But no one is going to reach your site when they look up `amazon.com`.

When people look up `amazon.com` in their browser (or by any other means) they will contact a name server in order to find an IP address. This name server  will give them an authoritative answer according to the name servers that `amazon.com` has set.

In the same way, when you set your own domain as the URL, this doesn't automatically make your domain point to your WordPress site either - you have to change your DNS records on your domain to point to some information WordPress provides to you to have your domain point to your WordPress site.

You can use a command like `dig amazon.com A +trace` to follow the process of this resolution and see how a domain name is resolved to an IP address.